# Trying to read numbers from a file but keep getting a Segmentation Error:11.-C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't quite see what's wrong with this code, I keep getting a segmentation fault:11 when it's run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int sum=0;
    FILE* filein=fopen("input(1).txt", "r");
    while(fscanf(filein, "%d", &a) > 0)
    {
        sum+=a;
    }
    fprintf(filein, "Sum = %d\n", sum);
    fclose(filein);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Chek that `filein` is not `NULL`, also, it should be `fscanf(filein, "%d", &a) == 1)`, not `> 1`

Comment: Also, you open `filein` for reading but are then writing to it later on.

Comment: Sure you want to write the sum to the file and not simply print to stdout?

Comment: Hi @Olaf, no I actually want to write to stdout.

Comment: That's exactly what my comment asked!

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code after you load in your file. If it never jumps into the if statement then your file is not being found or loaded.

```
if (filein != NULL) // Checks if the file was loaded. 
{
    while (fscanf(filein, "%d", &a) > 0)
    {
        sum += a;
    }
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum); // prints to command window. 
    fclose(filein);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being down voted? Let me know why. This was my first answer and I'm just trying to help..

Comment: don't know why we're getting downvoted here. That said, thank you for that! I think I have it figured out now but if I'll use that as a reference.